# how to use user defined environment variables in chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to use a user defined variable in my template resource path as below. But I am not sure how to retrieve the user defined environment variable in chef. Please help.

```
template "#{user_env_variable}/sys/test.xml" do  
  source "test.xml.erb"  
  owner user1  
  group user1  
  mode '0644'  
end
```

`user_env_variable` is the user defined environment variable in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access environment variables in ruby using `ENV`, e.g., `ENV['PATH']`. Translated to your code, this would be:

```rb
template "#{ENV['user_env_variable']}/sys/test.xml" do  
  source "test.xml.erb"  
  owner user1  
  group user1  
  mode '0644'  
end
```

Be warned: I would consider doing this a bad practice. What, if chef-client now runs as a system service or what if the environment variable is not defined? Probably, there's a cleaner way to reach your goal (if we would know it..).